# How to add keyframe gaps on timeline animation window?

Tags: unity, animation, frame-rate, time

I'm using Unity timeline windows to create a building animation. I have a building model with many parts for example every floor has own parent and 200 child objects.

[image]

In this parent as you can see I added position animations with recording but I want gap between them.

[image]

For example like this:

[image]

But it's too hard to adjust it manually for so many objects. Is there any easy alternative?